# npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL

Tags: node.js, npm

after making a software to my laptop I installed all the programs includes node js
my OS windows

```
$ node -v
v8.11.1
```

and the npm

```
$ npm -v
v5.6.0
```

when I tried to install npm globally it's gave me this error :

```
$ npm install -g
npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL
npm ERR! Could not install from "" as it does not contain a package.json 
file.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Aroma\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-04- 
07T11_10_29_184Z-debug.log
```

or even when I tried to install it locally to a repository it's gave me:

```
$ npm install
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 
'C:\Users\Aroma\Desktop\app\package.json'
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this 
file.
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 
'C:\Users\Aroma\Desktop\app\package.json'
npm WARN app No description
npm WARN app No repository field.
npm WARN app No README data
npm WARN app No license field.

up to date in 0.11s
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Show your package.json file

Answer (score 1):

Try this command to change the npm version: 
npm -g install npm@4.2.0 
 it works for me on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem. I solved in this way.

Step 1: Open the command prompt as an Administrator and run **npm install -g create-react-app** to solve the npx issue.

Step 2:  run  **npx create-react-app your-app-name**

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue.
What I did was to rename the package-lock.json by:

```
mv package-lock.json package.json
```

, and then this issue should be solved.

If you get the next issue of showing a message:
[...] / rollbackFailedOptional: verb npm-session xxxxxxxxxxx
, then you could do

1. sudo npm config rm proxy
2. sudo npm config rm https-proxy
3. sudo npm install npm@latest -g

These steps works for me.
Hope they could be helpful to you too.